# Please explain the fourth line in this C code

Tags: c

```
#include"studio.h"
void main() {
int i , j= 0, k;
k = i = 2 , j; // what's meaning of int , int ?
printf ( "%d", k );
}
```

can anyone please explain what's up with that int , int ..?

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator allows you to evaluate a second expression. `(a, b)` returns the value of expression `b`.

However, because the `=` has a higher priority than the comma operator, the values of `i`, `j` and `k` are respectively `2`, `0` and `2`.